Defining a sequence from a list or a table
I want to define a sequence from a list.
For example if I have the list
A={1, 2, 3, 34, -9, 18}
I want to define the sequence a[n], with
a[1]=1
a[2]=2
a[3]=3
a[4]=34
a[5]=-9
a[6]=18
without writing down the elements.
My list contains many more elements...
Thanks in advance.
Lefteris

a[i_]:=A[[i]]; a[6]

Do[a[i] = A[[i]], {i, 1, 6}]

check
a[#]& /@ Range@Length[A]

(* {1, 2, 3, 34, -9, 18} *)

But perhaps consider an association?
aa = AssociationThread[Range[Length@A] -> A];

aa[4]
(* 34 *)

and
PositionIndex[aa][34]
(* 4 *)


One possible way is to use MapIndexed
ClearAll[a]
lis={1,2,3,34,-9,18}
MapIndexed[Set[a[First[#2]],#1]&,lis]

And now your a[i] are all set.


Thanks a lot. It works perfect!

One way to do this would be via Part:
A := {1, 2, 3, 34, -9, 18};
a[n_] := Part[A, n];


or
A := {1, 2, 3, 34, -9, 18};
a[n_] := A[[n]];


Part[list, n] gives you the n.th element / part in list, so this would be the trivial way to do this.

You could also use Take:
A := {1, 2, 3, 34, -9, 18};
a[n_] := First[Take[A, {n, n}]];


Take[list, a, b] gives elements a through b of list aka if a = b would just give you a list containing the element at position a.

lis = {1, 2, 3, 34, -9, 18};


Using PositionIndex and KeyValueMap:
KeyValueMap[Set[a[First[#2]], #1] &]@PositionIndex[lis]

(*{1, 2, 3, 34, -9, 18}*)

a[4]

(*34*)


The most direct way is
ClearAll[A, a];
A = {1, 2, 3};
a[n_] := A[[n]];

However, there are two issues. One is restricting the
range of valid indexing. For example, in this test case
{a[-1], a[0], a[4]} gives unacceptable results. Thus,
you may want to restrict the possible valid indexes with
a[n_] := A[[n]] /;n>0&&n<=Length[A];
The other issue is if the list A is allowed to change.
The current code tracks changes in A. If A changes then
the corresponding values of a[n] will also change. If you
don't want this behavior, then you can do the following
Do[ a[n] = A[[n]], {n, Length[A]}];
in the beginning and then the values of a[n] will not
depend on any changes in A.
